# Copy attribute from DOM node into a dijit widget?

Tags: javascript, scala, lift, dojo

I have html markup like this

```
<button id="button1" onclick="alert='yup'"></button>
```

and I want to make a button widget using that DOM as an anchor

```
var button = new Button({label: "button"}, "button1")
```

How do I copy onclick attribute into button widget ? The reason I want to do this because web-framework I used (lift) add some function to button before I make it into dijit widget.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use your framework to add a data-dojo-type to your html and then use dojo parser to transform the whole thing into a widget?

Comment: I don't like to stick everything in HTML (actually, I already tried your solution and work pretty well). I think it is much cleaner to stick everything in js. I would like to know if this is possible

Comment: It is possible yeah.. depending on your dojo version i guess. IF your framework allows for it, you might put all the added functions into data-dojo-props='someFunc: function(param){// whatever}, someProp: someValue' on your tag

Comment: In the worst case you could always manually use DOM accessors to get the data from the DOM node but, as PEM said, doing things the Dojo way would probably be much cleaner.

Comment: I did some mock up using declarative style and compare it to hack using  dojo.attr. Declarative looks much nicer. I guess I will stick with declarative one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PEM is absolutely correct, use dojo parser for that (the keyword for onclick will then be with capital 'C' : "onClick='alert(true)'" or "data-dojo-props='onClick:function() {alert(true)}' ".

Anyways, here's one way to achieve it

```
var dom = dojo.byId('button1');
var fn = eval(dom.onclick.toString());
dom.onclick = null;
var button = new Button({label: "button", onClick:fn}, "button1");
```